# Python nltk won't work on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, nltk

I'm new to Python and Pycharm, so I'm having trouble being able to use nltk. I downloaded nltk using command prompt on windows. I'm able to run `from nltk.book import *` from the command prompt, but when I try to do it in Pycharm it doesn't recognize nltk. I only have one version of Python installed (3.6.4). If anyone could give me some information on this I would appreciate it. I've watched videos and read previous posts on here, but none of them worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check Pycharm Settings (Search for `Interpreter` and make sure it's pointing at the correct python install. Try putting the cursor on the error and Ctrl-enter to auto-resolve. PyCharm should offer to install packages if it can locate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's a path problem.

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

See if NLTK is in one of the directories shown. Your command prompt might reference a directory that Pycharm isn't looking at.